# Python: Extract a particular column(containing special characters) from csv file using pandas

Tags: python, csv, pandas, text-formatting

I have a file(tests.txt) containing data in the below Format:

```
NUMBER,\tFilename,\t\t\t\t\tTestName,\t\t\t\tConfig
001,\t\tFile1.csv,\t\tcube,\t\twidth height size
002,\t\tFile2.csv,\t\tsquare,\t\tlength param
```

Normally looks like:

```
HLM_TIER,    Filename,                  TestName,               Config
001,         File1.csv,                 cube,                   width height size
002,         File2.csv,                 square,                 length param
```

I want to extract a particular column(TestName) from this file.

### Code tried:

```
import pandas as pd
data = pd.read_csv('tests.txt', skipinitialspace=True)
TestName = data.TestName
TestName = TestName.strip(' \t')
```

### But, I get the following Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\temp.py", line 23, in <module>
    TestName = data.TestName
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py", line 2246, in __getattr__
    (type(self).__name__, name))
AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'TestName'
```

*I think that the error is due to the tabs in the column causing pandas to read the column as "\t\t\t\t\tTestName  \"*
But, i am not sure, how to resolve the issue.
**NOTE: I cannot change the "tests.txt" file.**

Comment: What happens if you also include the argument - skipinitialspace=True , to read_csv ?

Comment: Aren't dataframes accessed by key, `data['TestName']`...

Comment: @AnandSKumar: It does not work. Tried this "data = pd.read_csv('performance_tests.txt', skipinitialspace=True". But, no change.

Comment: Same error or did the error change ? What do you get as the result of print(data.columns)

Comment: When you use that you don't need strip .

Comment: @AnandSKumar: I want to do it using pandas, as the data set is very huge. So, Please do not change the subject. Regarding your query: Same Error. Result of print: **"Index([u'HLM_TIER', u'\t Filename', u'\t\t\t\t\tTestName',
       u'\t\t\t\tminidx Config'],
      dtype='object')"**

Comment: @riotburn: No, It says **KeyError: 'TestName'**

Comment: Can you copy paste the latest code you are using ? Also you do not need pandas or Python in question since they are already there in tags  it just clutters the title unnecessarily .

Comment: @Knbteja: please check it.

Comment: try `print data.keys()` and see whats available.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `converters` to strip the data as you read them in. For this you would need to create a function that does this stripping, and then you would need to pass that into a dict mapping the column to the function.

And you should also manually specify the column names using `names` argument and skip the header row.

Example -

```
def strip(x):
    try:
        return x.strip()
    except AttributeError:
        return x

col_names = ['HLM_TIER', 'Filename', 'TestName', 'Config', ...]
col_mapping = {key:strip for key in col_names}
data = pd.read_csv('tests.txt', names=col_names, converters=col_mapping)
```

Comment: Updated the code in question, Please check. Only change is "skipinitialspace=True", as suggested.

Comment: Let me try to reproduce your issue

Comment: @PrafulS Check the latest update, you would need to use `converters` (or some other processing after reading in the csv directly ).

Answer (score 1):

Can you just remove all the tabs:

```
from StringIO import StringIO

with open('test.txt', 'r') as f:
    df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(f.read().replace('\t', '')))
    df.TestName
```

Answer (score 0):

```
df = pd.read_csv('Foo.txt', delim_whitespace=True)
```

Comment: Can you explain more your answer please ?